# Какие можно использовать готовые JS библиотеки, чтобы генерировать графики такого типа?

Tags: javascript

Нужно на сайте генерировать необычный график (изображение графика ниже). Какие можно использовать готовые JS библиотеки, чтобы генерировать графики такого типа?

[image: Необычный график]

Comment: Что Вы имеете в виду под "готовыми библиотеками"?

Answer (score 3):

[Выбирайте, тут много...](http://socialcompare.com/en/comparison/javascript-graphs-and-charts-libraries)
Но я бы предпочел [Flot](http://www.flotcharts.org/) с плагином [Candlestick](http://jumflot.jumware.com/examples/Experimental/Candlestick.html)

Answer (score 2):

Знаю о библиотеке http://a-web.me/docs/AWeb.html,
позволяет строить графики такого типа http://a-web.me/controls.html#chart
(в выпадающем списке под графиком можно выбрать различные варианты отрисовки графика)

Знаю еще вот про эту библиотеку http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-ajax/

Ни одной из них пользоваться не приходилось, так что на счет удобства использования и того, насколько их можно кастомизировать, ничего сказать не могу.

Answer (score 1):

d3js.org в руки, полно примеров, полно графиков и не таких в том числе.

Comment: D3 офигенная библиотека для (инфо)графики. Вот конкретно [пример](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4061502), про который спрашивает OP. К тому же, интерактивный.